# laravel how to display foreign key attributes via json response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel and returning a json response for my datatable my controller is:

```
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $expense,
    ]);
```

and my ajax colums display data as below:

```
            {"data":"id"},
            {"data":"agency_id"},
            {"data":"amount"},
            {"data":"date"},
            {"data":"description"},
```

but instead of agency_id I want to display agency_name via foreign key.
this is how joined the tables:

```
$expense = DB::table('agency_exps')
                ->join('agencies','agency_exps.id','=','agencies.id')
                ->select('agency_exps.*','agencies.name')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Have you joined the tables using annotations in your Entity class?

Comment: @Dula I have, I edited and added the codes.

Comment: {"data":"name"} should display agency name, provided there is no column 'name' in agency_exps table.

Comment: @T.Shah is correct. You should be able to access the ``name`` using ``{"data":"name"}``. If you have a name column in ``agency_exps``, you can add ``->select('agency_exps.*','agencies.name as agency_name')`` and access it like ``{"data":"agency_name"}``.